# Grunt wont watch less

Tags: gruntjs, less

Having some problem when I am trying to run `grunt` in the terminal, I get an error saying:

> `"task "default" not found. use --force to continue.`

Have searched around for help, but none of it works, can somebody here help what is wrong? The code in the `gruntfile.js` is this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig {{
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        less: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'dist/css/style.css' : 'less/style.less'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: 'less/style.less',
                tasks: ['less']
            }
        },
    }};
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Comment: Use parenthesis  `()` and not curly braces `{}`. For instance change `grunt.initConfig {{ ... }};` to `grunt.initConfig({ ... });`